# Why is cipher text returned from RijndaelManaged different each time?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, rijndaelmanaged

I would like to use RijndaelManaged to encrypt a string with any salting so if I pass encrypt a string using the same key I will receive the same cipher text back.
The method I am calling looks like this

```
     public static string GetEncryptedData(string plainText)
    {
        var cipher = new RijndaelManaged();

        string keyString = "really long string"

        var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyString);
        cipher.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
        cipher.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        cipher.KeySize = 256;
        cipher.BlockSize = 256;

        var cryptoTransform = cipher.CreateEncryptor();
        byte[] stuffToEncrypt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        byte[] cipherText = cryptoTransform.TransformFinalBlock(stuffToEncrypt, 0, plainText.Length);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherText);
    }
```

I thought if I set

```
cipher.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
cipher.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
```

There would be no randomness introduced and the result will be the same each time this method is called with the same input like

```
GetEncryptedData("somestring")
```

but each time it runs it returns a diff value. What am I missing?

**Edit**

as pointed out on the accepted answer I forgot to set the key so adding this did the trick

```
cipher.Key = Convert.FromBase64String("C53wafJw3QmImGBN8Se9EnIJgiQq7LyoWHzUEFQI/B0=");
```

Comment: As a note, `new RijndaelManaged()` and `cipher.CreateEncryptor()` return objects which implement the `IDisposable` interface and therefore should be wrapped in `using` clauses to ensure proper deterministic disposal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're not setting the key, a different key is generated every time you call your method, so you get a different cipher text. You should set the `Key` property explicitly so that you're always using the same key.